# Is there a way to make DOM Changes to a single element when there is multiple elements sharing the same classname?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a menu for practice, that contains different categories of meals. (i.e breakfast, lunch, snacks, etc.) I am making this menu to where there are 8 rows that when *one* of them is clicked, it shows a previously hidden description about that particular item. I am having trouble implementing the JS behind showing the menu description. I am not sure if all of the rows need to have unique class names, but I am not sure exactly how to select one row when clicked and then produce the output for only that particular row. Here is my current code at the moment (Note: The description has not been created yet) Also, I am new to web development, so anything that would point me in the right direction, even if it's not a full answer will be helpful :)

HTML

```
<section class = "section section-menu">
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Breakfast-Figma.png" alt="Breakfeast img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;Breakfeast</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/CFA-Spicy-Chicken-Entree-Figma.png" alt="Spicy Chicken img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entreés</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Salad-Figma.png" alt="Salad img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Salads</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Large-Fries-Sides-Figma.png" alt="Fries img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sides</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Kids-Meal-Figma.png" alt="Kids Meal img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kid's Meals</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Milkshake-Treat-Figma.png" alt="Milkshake img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Treats</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/Beverage-Figma.png" alt="Beverage img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drinks</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class = "option">
            <div class = "option-container">
                <img src = "img/CFA-Dipping-Sauce-Figma.png" alt="Dipping Sauce img">
                <h3 class = "option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dipping Sauces & Dressings</h3>
            </div>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class = "dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </section>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
.section-menu {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.option {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  display: flex;
}

.option-container {
  width: max-content;
  display: flex;
}

.option-text {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Apercu-light;
}

.dropdown-arrow {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

No JS yet, because my attempts have yielded no noticeable results.

Comment: If a row is "particular", it should have one (or more) *additional* class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements do not *need* to have distinct class names, but you can use additional class names as needed and be as specific as needed when referencing elements with the specified class(es).

I recommend using the `id` attribute for distinct element selection to reference them in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Then use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to place a `click` `eventListener` on each of the `<div class="option">` elements. You can select them all in JavaScript with [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then apply event listeners in a `forEach` loop as follows.

*Note: although `options` has a `forEach` method like an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), it is actually an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)*

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
options.forEach(function(option) {
  option.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    if (element.tagName === "IMG") {console.log(element.src);return;}
    console.log(event.target.textContent.trim());
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="section section-menu">
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Breakfast-Figma.png" alt="Breakfeast img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;Breakfeast</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/CFA-Spicy-Chicken-Entree-Figma.png" alt="Spicy Chicken img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Entreés</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Salad-Figma.png" alt="Salad img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Salads</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Large-Fries-Sides-Figma.png" alt="Fries img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sides</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Kids-Meal-Figma.png" alt="Kids Meal img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Kid's Meals</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Milkshake-Treat-Figma.png" alt="Milkshake img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Treats</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/Beverage-Figma.png" alt="Beverage img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Drinks</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <div class="option-container">
      <img src="img/CFA-Dipping-Sauce-Figma.png" alt="Dipping Sauce img">
      <h3 class="option-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dipping Sauces & Dressings</h3>
    </div>
    <ion-icon name="chevron-up-circle-outline" class="dropdown-arrow"></ion-icon>
  </div>
</section>
```